# Clean install pycharm 4.5 over 4.0

Tags: python, installation, ide, pycharm, updates

I want to update from pycharm 4.0 to 4.5. From what I understand it's just extracting the archive and use it. However my previous installation (4.0) was not done similarly see the result of : find / -name pycharm 2> /dev/null

```
/usr/bin/pycharm
/usr/share/pycharm
/usr/share/pycharm/helpers/pycharm
/usr/share/doc/pycharm
/usr/lib/pycharm
/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintInstall/tmp/pycharm-community-4.0.2/helpers/pycharm
```

Could you indicate me the way of properly removing the previous install.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was installed outside of the package manager, I don't see what's wrong with just removing those directories.

`# find / -name "pycharm" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

If it was installed with your package manager, just use it to remove.

Comment: You highlighted something: pycharm can be find in the packet manager. I was stupidly thinking that I had installed it outside of it. I keep in mind your command line but next time I will just delete the folder of the current installation.